# Datatables: dynamic columns and huge amount of data

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) with ajax data request (json format) and dynamic columns load. This is my actual code:

```
var tableData;
var tableName='#iuprTable';

$(document).ready(function (){

    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "table/"+document.getElementById("hiddenIdCar").value,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},  
        beforeSend: function() {
            waitingModal.showPleaseWait();
        },
        success: function(data,status,xhr){
            //No exception occurred
            if(data.success){
                tableData = data.result;
                $.each(tableData.columns, function (k, colObj) {
                    var str = '<th data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<b>NAME</b>:'+ colObj.parName + '<br><b>DESCRIPTION</b>:' + colObj.description + '<br><b>NOTE</b>: ' + colObj.note + '"></i>' + colObj.parName + '</th>';
                    $(str).appendTo(tableName+'>thead>tr');
                });
            } else {
                waitingModal.hidePleaseWait();
                notifyMessage(data.result, 'error');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,e){
            window.location.href = "/500";
        }
    }).complete(function() {
        //initialize datatable
        if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( tableName ) ) {
            var iuprTable = $(tableName).DataTable({
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollX:        true,
                scrollY:        '60vh',
                paging:         false,
                "data": tableData.data,
                "columns": tableData.columns,
                fixedColumns:   {
                    leftColumns: 4
                },
                "initComplete": function(settings){
                    //TOOLTIP cell
                    $(tableName+ ' tbody td').each( function (k, cellObj){
                        this.setAttribute( 'title', cellObj.innerText );
                        this.setAttribute( 'data-toggle', "tooltip" );
                    });
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
                        container: 'body'
                    }); 
                    //add timeout because otherwise user could see a too fast waiting modal
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        waitingModal.hidePleaseWait();
                    }, 1000);       
                } 
            });
        }
        else {
            iuprTable.ajax.url("table/"+document.getElementById("hiddenIdCar").value).load();
        }
    }); 
});

function notifyMessage(textMessage, typeMessage){
    $.bootstrapGrowl(textMessage, {
        type: typeMessage, // (null, 'info', 'error', 'success')
    });
}
```

Since I may have 300 rows and 300 columns, with this numbers the page becomes slow. I read about server side processing and I was wondering how can I increase performace.
I have found 2 solutions:

1)Server side processing: ask to server only the showed rows

2)Client side: the json returns all the rows but only some of them are showed in a specific time, when user scrolls the data are updated (the page is faster after an initial loading).

The first solution is most complicated than client side processing because I should change web services. Do you have an advice for me? How can I implement these solutions? Thanks

Comment: You seem to already know your choices, so all I can say is that #1 will have more performance benefit, #2 is easier to implement.

Comment: yes, but I don't know how I can implement them particularly with dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

Use server side pagination with limit and offset of 50 per page etc

And index your database with respective referral columns that will improve performance for sure..

If possible also can go with cache query like memcached etc

Comment: this is for query, my problem is with datatables